# For class diagrams, is it within convention to have a class A storing an ArrayList of class B that is modifiable by class C?

Tags: uml, software-design, class-diagram

The simplified scenario is that you have customers that can make a booking and you have managers that can interact with those bookings. Along with classes for "Customer" and "Manager", there is a class "Booking" that represents each booking.

Is it valid to have a class "Bookings" specifically for storing an ArrayList of all objects of "Booking" and having operations for interacting with these "Booking" objects (e.g. add, remove, modify and list) that any "Manager" is able to use?

[image: Diagram of the described scenario]

I was not sure how Manager class fits into the scenario, in terms of convention. Also not shown is that Manager is a child of "Staff" class as part of the full scenario (not described here).

Comment: I'd just simply associate `Manager` with `Bookings`. So he can browse the bookings. `Manager` would probably a specialization of `User`(like `Customer`) depending on some authorization system.  And for the `Customer` I'd make a facade to `Bookings` to show only the customer`s bookings.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

> Is it valid to have a class "Bookings" specifically for storing an ArrayList of all objects of "Booking" and having operations for interacting with these "Booking" objects (e.g. add, remove, modify and list) that any "Manager" is able to use?

Visibly *Bookings* is only a collection of *Booking*, you do not need a specific class for that, collections exist by themselves

> For class diagrams, is it within convention to have a class A storing an ArrayList of class B that is modifiable by class C

without the class *Bookings* we do not have A,B and C, anyway to answer to that question out of that context in UML there is nothing against that, nor encouraging that. I can just say independently of UML while the collection is own by A the fact C can modify it can be dangerous without warning A or asking A to do itself

> I was not sure how Manager class fits into the scenario

*Manager* can be the class owning the collection of *Booking*

[image]

Comment: probably the DV has a reason, but which one ?

Comment: @qwerty_so I cannot really myself, not because of the DV itself, but because just say "wrong / I do not like" is just useless (to put it nicely), an associated remark to explain seems normal

Comment: Yes, me and you seem to be different ;-) In most cases I explain my DV - and often enough I get barked at. I somehow can understand why people just DV anonymously. There should be a mandatory text, but that has been discussed on meta and it will not happen (now).

Comment: @qwerty_so yes to have a mandatory text on DV is a loooong discussion

Comment: If _Manager_ class has an ArrayList of _Booking_ class, wouldn't the _Booking_ objects belong to a specific object of _Manager_? Is it possible to represent a way for any _Manager_ to interact with any _Booking_? Rather than have all _Booking_ objects belong to only one _Manager_ object.

Comment: a class diagram shows a static point of view ( definition of classes etc), the interaction you speak about is more part of a dynamic view (interaction, activity etc), anyway if you *really* want to show that in a class diagram you can use a dependency or an association not supporting an attribute, but again do you *really* want to show that in a class diagram ? If you have several manager yes it is better to not own the list in them but elsewhere, anyway not just in an object being a list

Comment: @chrisjt asking a Manager (you can rename that class anyway), like in the real life where a customer cannot create a booking by himself, else I immediately make a booking to the moon :-)

Comment: I was thinking both _Customer_ and _Manager_ can make _Booking_, with _Manager_ having additional operations it can perform on _Booking_